# Send Castle Object as a parameter in Resolve

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have a class builder that takes the following parameter:

```
public FolderAndFileManagment(IWindsorContainer container)
{
    var config = container.Resolve<IEcommerceConfiguration>();

    ReadFolderLocation = config.ReadFolderLocation;
    DropFolderLocation = config.DropFolderLocation;
    directoryRepository = container.Resolve<IDirectoryRepository>();

}
```

The registration of the component looks like this:

```
WindsorContainer.Register(Component.For<IFolderAndFileManagment>().ImplementedBy<FolderAndFileManagment>().Named("FolderAndFileManagment")
                             .Attribute("id").Eq("FolderAndFileManagment")
                             .Attribute("service").Eq(typeof(IFolderAndFileManagment).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                             .Attribute("type").Eq(typeof(FolderAndFileManagment).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                             .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

And the call for the resolver looks like this:

```
public static bool Initialize(IWindsorContainer container)
{
    _container = container;
    var config = _container.Resolve<IEcommerceConfiguration>();
    _fileManagment = _container.Resolve<IFolderAndFileManagment>(_container);
    return true;
}
```

But I get the following error when using the resolve function:

> Missing dependency.
>   Component FolderAndFileManagment has a dependency on Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer, which could not be resolved.
>   Make sure the dependency is correctly registered in the container as a service, or provided as inline argument.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using this overload of `Resolve`:

```
T Resolve<T>(object argumentsAsAnonymousType);
```

So, you need to make an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) with field names that match the arguments in the constructor of the type you're trying to resolve.  Since your constructor is:

```
public FolderAndFileManagment(IWindsorContainer container)
```

You should call `Resolve` like so:

```
fileManagment = _container.Resolve<IFolderAndFileManagment>(
                    new { container = _container });
```

Comment: this T Resolve<T>(object argumentsAsAnonymousType); no longer in version 6 , what else we can use to mimic this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing somekind of you own implementation of [TypeFactory](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). Why don`t you use it? It is very powerful.